# Problem with Table resizing in baposter

Tags: tables, baposter

I am not an expert in latex, and I am using the baposter template.
My problem is that I coudn't find a way to reduce the tab width (because it is way too wide for my column)..I've been looking on the internet and on one of the sites it was adviced to use the adjustbox pakage and it is what I did...
However I get plenty of errors..

Is there anybody that can help me?

Here are the lines where it seems something is wrong..

Many thanks.

```
\begin{adjustbox}{keepaspectratio,width=0.9\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Area Ratio} & \textbf{Energy Spectrum} & \textbf{Diameter Spectrum}\\
\midrule
 O(d,p$_1$)/C(d,p$_0$) & 3.54 & 3.56 \\
 O(d,p$_1$)/O(d,p$_0$) & 7.96 & 7.19 \\
 %3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table caption}
\end{center}
\end{adjustbox}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A minimal working example (MWE) would help. Are fixed-width-column an option for you?

Answer (score 2):

Using `adjustbox` in this situation has some disadvantages, for example the font size won't match your surrounding content. Also using `\begin{center}...\end{center}` inside an adjustbox does not make much sense (this is also what caused the errors with your fragment).

---

At the moment the width of your columns is determined by the long headers. If you split them for example in two lines, your table will become more compact.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Area} & \textbf{Energy} & \textbf{Diameter}\\
\textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Spectrum} & \textbf{Spectrum}\\
\midrule
 O(d,p$_1$)/C(d,p$_0$) & 3.54 & 3.56 \\
 O(d,p$_1$)/O(d,p$_0$) & 7.96 & 7.19 \\
 %3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Not sure what the context of the table actually is, but "ratio" sounds, like it might be displayed as "real" fraction, that would save even more space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Area} & \textbf{Energy} & \textbf{Diameter}\\
\textbf{Ratio} & \textbf{Spectrum} & \textbf{Spectrum}\\
\midrule\addlinespace
$\displaystyle\frac{O(d,p_1)}{C(d,p_0)}$ & 3.54 & 3.56 \\\addlinespace
$\displaystyle\frac{O(d,p_1)}{O(d,p_0)}$ & 7.96 & 7.19 \\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]